# How to write Test Class in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Can any one help me to write test class for below mentioned code

trigger ContactTriggerWithList1 on Contact (before insert) {

```
List<Account> lacc = [select Id, Name, Type from Account];

for(Contact c :trigger.New)
{
    
    for(Account a :lacc)
    {
        if(c.AccountId==a.Id)
        {
            c.Type__c=a.Type;
        }
    }
}
```

}

*********************Test Class*******************************
@isTest
public class ContactTriggerWithList1_TriggerHandler {

```
@isTest

static void test_insertContact()
{
    Account a = new Account(name='TestAccount', Type='Prospect');
    insert a;
    
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.LastName= 'TestContact';
    if(c.AccountId==a.Id)
    {
      c.Type__c=a.Type;
    }
   
    insert c;
    System.assertEquals(c.Type__c, a.Type);
 

}
```

}

This test class is giving 85% coverage. Can anyone help here? It is not covering C.Type__c == a.Type portion. Even though, I have written System.assert method as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In test methods, you're generally responsible for setting up the test data appropriately.

You're not setting the `AccountId` on your test contact in your test method, so when you reach the `if(c.AccountId == a.Id)` part in your trigger, it never evaluates to true, you never execute that code in the test, and thus you don't get coverage for it.

---

Your test method should not have the following lines in it:

```
if(c.AccountId==a.Id)
{
    c.Type__c=a.Type;
}
```

You want the thing you're testing, *your trigger*, to do that update (if it's appropriate to do so). Having that code directly in your test method defeats the purpose of the test (it doesn't get executed as-is, but it would be if you updated your test setup to be correct).

---

While it's not causing an issue, the nested loop where you check `if(a.Id == b.Id)` is extraordinarily wasteful. You should store the result of your account query in a `Map<Id, Account>`, and then check if the contact's accountId exists in the map. This removes the need for the nested loop, and turns your O(n^2) solution into a much better O(2n) solution.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. It really helped me. I forgot that part( to set up the account Id on contact record). I removed those lines and now it is giving 100% coverage.

Comment: @hakimupadhyay Coverage is fine, but don't forget that the real utility of writing tests is in the assertions you make. You can have 100% coverage on a class/method that returns "5" when you ask "what is 2 + 2?", but that doesn't change the fact that the code is wrong. You should strive not for coverage, but to _test many different paths of execution in your code_. Assertions ensure your results are what you expect, testing many paths ensures your code is robust, and together they automatically lead to high coverage.

Comment: Definitely Derek. Thanks for providing the valuable suggestion